# apk reinstall error "App not Install" after adding New Packages Micocharts and Microcharts.Forms

Tags: android, installation, xamarin.forms, apk, android-install-apk

I have created a sample app and signed an apk using adHoc which is successfully installed on my phone. After adding one page with microcharts i have increased the version of app and created new apk with adhoc but while installing installation failed with message "App not installed". I need to know what am i missing or any permission required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you creat the new apk with the same signature ？

Comment: Yes I have created new apk with same signature.

Comment: Did you install via adb command ? like `adb install -r xxx.apk`.

Comment: I am new to xamarin so I don't know how to run adb command on my physical device

Comment: I am just creating apk and sending apk file to my device via whatsapp.

Comment: Try to use adb install your apk,first connect your device,you will see it in your device list of visual studio,then open the `cmd` and navigate to your APK directory and run `adb install -r xxx.apk`

Comment: I have tried it gives error : Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.companyname.wms-xxFpD1iI0ylnIxpSMp3_mg==: Package /data/app/com.companyname.wms-xxFpD1iI0ylnIxpSMp3_mg==/base.apk code is missing]

Comment: Use the signed apk,it will has an custom path when you archive via adHoc.

Comment: Have the same problem now and I'm using signed apk